# iPhone XS doesn't have UDID

Tags: ios, iphone, udid, ios12, apple-developer

I want to add an iPhone XS UDID in the Apple developer portal but I am unable to find the UDID in iTunes and without adding the UDID I am unable to run my app on the iPhone XS. I tried adding the ECID and SEID but it didn't work.

I couldn’t find anything about the disappearance of the UDID on Google either.

Can anyone help me figure out how to register the iPhone XS in the Apple developer portal?

Comment: It is not showing UDID I have checked it.

Comment: When you connect the device to your computer and try and build and run via Xcode, it will offer to add the device to the developer portal for you. If users are installing via TestFlight it will also happen automatically. Why do you need to do it manually?

Comment: Using terminal to find udid for new iPhones and iPads : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997294/342794

Comment: Terminal is useful alternative when team members (designers, testers, etc) don't have XCode installed. Or need to access UDIDs for devices remotely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997294/342794

Answer (score 36):

For the iPhone XS/XS Max and possibly other iPhones which do not show UUID in Itunes:
- Open Xcode
- Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Select your iPhone -> Use the "identifier" as shown below:
[image]

Comment: This is clearly the best answer - no need to leave Xcode!

Comment: But a need for your testers to install XCode

Comment: Also complicates things when you have a remote device farm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997294/342794

Comment: @AshleyMills developer portal says its not valid. Any idea ?

Answer (score 19):

- Go to "->About This Mac".
- Click on "System Report" and select "USB".
- Find your phone and the "Serial Number" field is what you are after.
- Copy this value and paste it into the developer portal when you register a new device; you will need to insert a - after the 8th digit.

You can also get the "identifier" from the Xcode "devices" window or have Xcode update the portal directly.

[image: Screenshot of the USB Settings to locate UDID]

Comment: It keeps complaining that this is not a valid UDID :(

Comment: Can you add the device through Xcode? I know iPhone XS serial number formats have changed, but i would have thought that the developer portal was ready for the change. I don't have an XS to test on.

Comment: This approach works, it's just missing a dash after the 8th character for the new UDID format.

Comment: Adding a '-' is important. Just added a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. So it turns out that the UDID is CORRECT...but for some reason UDID needs to be lower case!!! After I lower cased everything, it was then accepted. @Mehul

Comment: @jhub1, Ok l will check and let you know soon. Thanks for your response.

Comment: They did not need to be lower case for me, but the dash in the right place (after the first 8 digits) is important.

Comment: The above approach works. On the right top window, "USB 3.0 Bus" is selected by default but the selection should be "iPhone". Then only you will get the correct serial number. Copy and paste the value. You then need to add a – after the 8th digit. For Ex: if you got a serial number as "98gfhgd67f1a06b4f60156f1949fbytrd205c1f0", after adding - it should like this: "98gfhgd6-7f1a06b4f60156f1949fbytrd205c1f0".

Answer (score 4):

You can compile the UDID from the ECID that is shown by iTunes with the following formula (for XS and XS Max)

**0000CHIP-00ECID**

The CHIP version in the XS/XS Max case is 8020 ([source for it](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/CHIP))

So if you want to compute the UDID for an XS/XS Max (and I believe the XR has the same chip), then you'll need to replace the ECID with your own in:

**00008020-00ECID**

To find the ECID, connect the iPhone to iTunes and click the serial number, the ECID will show up.

[image]

Edit: For the XR the formula is: **00008020-000ECID**, because the ECID has one less character

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the UDID for the XS is(if you are a dev that is)

1. Connect your device to you mac
2. Open Xcode
3. Open Window->Devices and Simulators
4. Select your device
5. You will see identifier in a similar screen like the one below

[image: Xcode Image identifier]

Answer (score 3):

**Use terminal "system_profiler" to find the UDID for attached devices**

If you're comfortable using Terminal, you can paste this command in to Terminal or save it as a [script or alias](https://pastebin.com/xmjgJpbH).

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType -detailLevel mini | \
grep -e iPhone -e Serial | \
sed -En 'N;s/iPhone/&/p'
```

Paste that text into Terminal and press enter to run system_profiler for the USB devices, and then filter for only the iPhone's UDID from the pretty-long output. Again, be sure to add the necessary hyphen after the first eight digits for iPhone XS and XS Max devices.

output on terminal:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType -detailLevel mini | \
grep -e iPhone -e Serial | \
sed -En 'N;s/iPhone/&/p'
Output:
2018-10-25 12:57:06.527 system_profiler[23461:6234239] SPUSBDevice: 
IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed 0xe0003a3e
        iPhone:
          Serial Number: 3aeac....4145
```

Ignore following failures

`2018-10-25 12:57:06.527 system_profiler[23461:65234239] SPUSBDevice: IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed 0xe0003a3e`

Look for `Serial Number: 3aeac........4145`

Alias:

```
# find UDID
alias fudid="system_profiler SPUSBDataType -detailLevel mini | grep -e iPhone -e Serial | sed -En 'N;s/iPhone/&/p'"
```

From: https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_11_19_how_to_find_your_iphone_udid/

Answer (score 3):

**Open Xcode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Select your iPhone -> Identifier**

Copy the value for Identifier. This is the UDID

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just combining all the different answers form the internet:-

**In MacOS:-**

For iPhones which do not show UDID in Itunes, There are two approaches for those who are using MacOS:-

If you are a developer you can get the UDID by both the approaches. But if you need UDID number of your client's iPhone or someone else's who is sitting in onsite or someone else's who does not have Xcode in their Mac, for them 2nd approach is the best.

1. Connect iPhone using USB in Mac. Open Xcode --> Window --> Devices & Simulators --> Select your iPhone -> Copy the "identifier". That is the iPhones UDID number.

   For ex:- It should like this "98gfhgd6-7f1a06b4f60156f1949fbytrd205c1f0.
2. Connect iPhone using USB in Mac. Click Apple icon on the left top corner "" --> "About This Mac" --> "System Report" -- Select "USB" on the left panel --> Select "iPhone" on the right top window --> Copy and paste the Serial Number value. You then need to add a – after the 8th digit.

   For Ex: if you got a serial number as
   "98gfhgd67f1a06b4f60156f1949fbytrd205c1f0", after adding - it should
   like this: "98gfhgd6-7f1a06b4f60156f1949fbytrd205c1f0".

**In Windows:-**

Note: If you’re using the Windows PC, then you can use third party tools like iFunBox,etc for Windows, to get the UDID for iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max. It is a much easier method. iFunBox for Mac doesn’t seem to provide the UDID.

Answer (score 0):

Must be update to XCode10 and click Window -> Devices & Simulators -> Select your iPhone -> Use the "identifier"

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get UDID of your iPhone XS using https://get.udid.io

Comment: Why is this -1 ? I use it for long time with pleasure. I can suggest this page.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using macOS catalina, and there is no iTunes any more, you may do the following:

1. Go to Finder, select the device from the side bar
2. Select the General Tab so you can see the device name, model number, and other details, as in the image below:
   [image]
3. Finally, click on the model number below the device name, and it will change to show you the serial number and UDID, as in the image below.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

The iPhone XS and XS max no longer have UDID readily displayed in iTunes. The previous steps works but need to add one more which is to lower case the UDID retrieved.

> 1.Connect iPhone to Mac
>
> 2.Go to About This Mac
>
> 3.Click on "System Report" and select "USB" from left panel.
>
> 4.Find your iphone and look for the "Serial Number" field. This is what you need.
>
> 5.Copy this "Serial Number" and register the device in the developer portal. Make sure developer portal recognizes the device model. (As
>   the developer portal recognizes the device model for a valid UDID when
>   registering the device).
>
> The serial number will be without hyphen. Make sure to add hyphen
>   after first 8 characters. Example: XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Add
**6. Lower case all letters.**

Comment: This is identical to @Paulw11's answer

Comment: They did not need to be lower case for me.

Answer (score -2):

1.Connect iPhone to Mac

2.Go to About This Mac

3.Click on "System Report" and select "USB" from left panel.

4.Find your iphone and look for the "Serial Number" field. This is what you need.

5.Copy this "Serial Number" and register the device in the developer portal. Make sure developer portal recognizes the device model. (As the developer portal recognizes the device model for a valid UDID when registering the device).

6. The serial number will be without hyphen. Make sure to add hyphen after first 8 characters. Example: XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: This is identical to @Paulw11's answer

Comment: @AshleyMills it is NOT Paul's answer. I followed his answer and it didn't work. That's why I copy pasted his answer and added one additional but critical step.