# Unable to get UDID from iPhone Xs Max | iOS | Apple | iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, udid

I need to get the UDID of my iPhone Xs Max to test my App.
Apparently, That does not work on the iPhone Xs Max
[image]

Comment: You must install profiles from a valid `https` URL.  That site is not using a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone XS don't have UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473290/iphone-xs-dont-have-udid)

Comment: You can try this site https://webapp.diawi.com/

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because iOS 12 requires device management profiles to be installed over a valid HTTPS connection.  That site's certificate is not trusted.

Answer (score 2):

### Better to use direct System Report or XCode to find UDIDs:

> **Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473809/342794 
>   or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997294/342794**

### Details on using udid.io (Specific to this question)

It seems you are using [udid.io](http://get.udid.io) (http://get.udid.io -- No "https" !!??) to get UDID without any app installation or connecting to USB. **security concern**, this would fail with iOS 12.

Note: Even for older iOS devices, As it installs a certificate on the mobile device. Not really a recommended way. Could be a shortcut in case you don't have an alternative. Say if you have a large pool of QA devices and don't have physical access to the devices (device farms accessible over the network) and don't care about installing a certificate from the untrusted source. Even in that case, look for an alternative to use a script to find UDID for all connected devices (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997294/342794).

On supported iOS:

a. Asks to install a certificate that gets deleted automatically.

b. Shows UDID on the browser with an option to email

Screenshots:

[image: Asks to install a certificate that gets deleted automatically]

[image: Shows UDID on the browser with an option to email]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **Xcode**
2. Go to **Window**
3. Select **Devices & Simulators**
4. Select your **iPhone**
5. Copy the value for **Identifier**

See the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53041428/1722622