# How to find UDID in the new iPhone Xs and iPhone Xs Max?

Tags: ios, iphone-xs-max, iphone-xs

How to find UDID in the new iPhone Xs and iPhone Xs Max?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming and development? You use Apple's assigned Advertiser ID or you generate a UUID on the fly for use in your app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac.

[image]

2. Navigate to  -> About This Mac.

[image]

3. Click on System Report and select USB.

[image]

4. Click on iPhone, and copy the value next to the Serial Number label.

[image]

5. Copy and paste the value. You then need to add a dash (-) after the 8th digit.

Sample Format = XXXXXXXX–XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

6. This is the UDID for the iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max.

The above steps will surely help you.

It is working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming and development? You should provide the code to perform the task.

Comment: Thank you SO much.  I've never seen anything so simple, more frustrating than this.  Holy hell, what is Apple thinking?????  They should just have an information button on the Developer page.  Trying to develop on an iPhone is like some kind of secret society.  Despicable on Apple's part, one of many.

Answer (score 1):

This [question has detailed discussion & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476637/unable-to-get-udid-from-iphone-xs-max-ios-apple-iphone/52996340#52996340) with options to use:

- Terminal to find UDID via `system_profiler`
- XCode
- System Report
- 3rd party apps & web-links.

[Unable to get UDID from iPhone Xs Max | iOS | Apple | iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476637/unable-to-get-udid-from-iphone-xs-max-ios-apple-iphone/52996340#52996340)

Answer (score 0):

Combined all the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53313233/4527624) from the internet and included steps for both Mac and Windows.