# How can I get my UDID of my device (ios 12) without connecting to PC

Tags: iphone, ios12, udid

I was using site http://get.udid.io

It is working fine in my device before I update it to ios 12. But now I am getting an error message like as follows.

[image]

Anyone can please tell me why this is happening and suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get UDID from iPhone Xs Max | iOS | Apple | iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476637/unable-to-get-udid-from-iphone-xs-max-ios-apple-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed.

Now https://get.udid.io uses HTTPS so it is compatible with iOS12+.