# iPhone Xs and Xs Max no UDID showing on iTunes?

Tags: iphone, udid

UDIDs are not showing in the latest version of iTunes 12.9 with iPhone Xs and Xs Max running iOS 12.

Does anyone know how to obtain the UDID from the new iTunes?

So far I managed to get a 24-digit code from Xcode. I am using iPhone Xs Max, the device is showing up as an iPhone 4 in Xcode!

It seems like Apple has changed the UDID format from 40 digits to 24 digits, and a hyphen has to be added after the first 8 digits for the registration to work. e.g. 00008020-

Note: the code that shows in Xcode does not include the “-“, it needs to be added manually. It will not work if you paste the 24-digit code onto the device registration page.

Just wondering if anyone managed to get the UDID on iTunes without using Xcode? Or third party softwares?

This is the method I used so far:

1. Connect iPhone to Xcode.
2. Windows - Devices and simulators.
3. Copy the 24-digit indentifier code.
4. Add a hyphen after the first 8 digits.
5. Register on the apple dev account device list.

Let us know if there is an easier way.

Hope this helps, and can save people some time.

Comment: I was able to get the correct "UDID" from Xcode by going to Window->Devices and Simulators, then selecting the correct device and copying the number labeled "Identifier" (which had the dash)

Answer (score 3):

For a non-Xcode answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473809/3303337. Quoting that answer:

> - Go to "->About This Mac".
> - Click on "System Report" and select "USB".
> - Find your phone and the "Serial Number" field is what you are after.
> - Copy this value and paste it into the developer portal when you register a new device.

Then just inject a dash after the first 8 digits.

Comment: Related question: stackoverflow.com/a/52473809/342794

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the format has changed, it's like that now :
00007020-0018598X0X90003X

It's called "Identifier" in :

`Xcode > Window > Devices & Simulators`

Source : https://iphonesoft.fr/2018/10/08/apple-change-format-udid-l-iphone-xs

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get UDID as well as other device information by using the app called "Apple Configurator 2".
Here is the app link.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like dpalmer's answer, you can use the System Report. To get the System Report's serial number on the Terminal without as much clicking, you can paste in this command:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType -detailLevel mini | \
grep -e iPhone -e Serial | \
sed -En 'N;s/iPhone/&/p'
```

Output:

```
2018-10-25 12:57:06.527 system_profiler[23461:6234239] SPUSBDevice: IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService failed 0xe0003a3e
iPhone:
    Serial Number: 3aeac....4145
```

You may ignore the `failed 0xe0003a3e` part and get the `Serial Number: 3aeac....4145`

From my blog post on the topic, that includes methods to get the UDID on Windows as well: https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_11_19_how_to_find_your_iphone_udid/

As everyone notes, you need to manually stick in the hyphen after the first eight digits.

Comment: Useful in case of QA device farms. Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473809/342794