# How to get UDID for Phone XS, iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max?

Tags: ios, ios12, iphone-xs, iphone-xs-max

I'm trying to access UDID of my iPhone XR/XS/XS Max, but not able to access from this phone. Anyone help me out?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473809/342794