# Add iOS device to Provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-developer

I have a new iPhoneXS, "which doesn't have an UDID" - as said by the tester. Where can i find another identifier to add it to registered devices on Apple Developer portal?
Thanks

Comment: "which doesn't have an UDID" Of course it does. And in any case, no need to use the portal. Attach the device to the computer, open the Devices window in Xcode, register the device for development, done.

Comment: @matt I don't need to do a local test, i need to let a tester far from me to use it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tangentential to programming

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473290/iphone-xs-doesnt-have-udid/52473809#52473809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Apple phone have a `UDID`

Please open your device safari browser and write this url `https://www.getudid.io/`

This will ask to install please click on it then you can able to show your device UDID

Comment: I know all Apple devices have one... but the tester i need to register said me "it has no UDID"... i'll try with this website, thanks