# Where can I find the UDID on Apple products since fall, 2018?

Tags: ios, udid

I’m an Apple developer who has always registered devices by entering the required UDID in my Apple Developer’s account. The process to get your UDID has always been the same: hook up your device to iTunes, click on the device, and then click on the Serial Number in the device summary screen. The serial number changes to the UDID.

Since the release of the iPhone XS, XS Max, and the 2018 iPad Pro, this ID is no longer available in iTunes. I’ve looked everywhere and even contacted Apple support and no one knows where this ID is?!

*Update and clarification:* While it has come to my attention that this can be done in Xcode (and that's good for me), the client has nothing but Windows PCs and iTunes to accompany their iPad Pros.  I need **a solution that doesn't involve Xcode** and will permit them to get me their UDIDs in a non-technical way.

Comment: You can easily get it in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487710/1187415

Comment: Sorry Martin, I've updated the question with the reason I was asking in the first place.  None of my clients have Macs or Xcode (just iPads and iTunes on Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, Apple changed this on all hardware released after fall 2018. The process still uses iTunes though. As before, connect your device to your computer and open iTunes. Click on the small icon to access the device Summary screen (here is where things change). From here, you’ll need to make a physical backup of your device; your UDID is the filename of this backup. 
[image]

To get the filename (your UDID), you’ll need to navigate to the folder where the backup was created.

**On Mac (OSX)**

- Open Finder Hold down the Option button and click Go from the top
  menu, then Library (you need to hold down Option to see “Library”).
- Click Application Support > MobileSync > Backup. Your backup will be
  in this folder.
- I personally right-click on the folder to rename it,
  then copy the filename and paste it into my Developer Account Device
  Registration window.

**On Windows**

- Open a Run Window (Start > Run, OR Windows Button+R)
- Enter %appdata%
- Click Apple Computer > MobileSync > Backup
- Your backup will be in this folder.

Comment: *“For security reasons, Apple changed this ...”* – do you have any reference for this? I wonder what the security problem should be, in particular if (as you say) the  UDID can still be determined easily.